# При помощи Grid сделать список в строку

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

Не соображу как при помощи Grid сделать список в строку (количество элементов LI неизвестно, генерируется автоматически)

```css
ul {
  display:grid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item-4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item-5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

repeat в общем т.е повторить одну фракцию пять раз

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">link5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да, это я понял, но это если известно сколько будет LI. А если они генерируются и каждый раз разное количество их

Comment: если не известно то на js узнать сколько и подставить в это свойство

Answer (score 1):

```css
grid-auto-columns: min-content;
grid-auto-flow: column;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]